# Javascript do not submit form TRUE

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("form1").submit();
document.getElementById("form2").submit();}
</script>

<form id="form1" action="php/create.php">
Name </br><input  type="text" name="inputName" value="" id=""> </input>
Hemsida </br><input  type="text" name="inputPage" value="http://" id=""> </input>

<input type="button" onclick="return myFunction()" value="Submit"/>

</form>
<form id="form2" action="php/createhemerb.php">
<input type="text" name="inputFon" value="" id="fnid" hidden/>
<input  type="text" name="inputJob" value="" id="fnid" hidden/>
</form>
```

I reach out to the php files but the both come out "please fill out the form 1" and "please fill out the form 2"

```
if(!$_POST['submit']) {
echo "please fill out the form";
header ('Location: please fill out the form 1');}
```

I have tried things back and fourth for hours i can not get it to work.

Comment: 1. Inline JavaScript is bad. 2. Your function does not return anything.

Comment: Also, why have the javascript submit at all? Combining into one form would be easier. Also, if you do want to use javascript submit, use e.preventDefault;

Comment: I have a search form in between the two forms that is why i got two, but would it work if i just put the same ID on both?

Answer (score 1):

Please do the following to fix your issue:

1. Add `method='post'` to your forms
2. If you intend to check the value of `$_POST['submit']`, you need to name your button 'submit'.
3. You can't use echo and then header(''), it will set a 'header already sent exception'.
4. header('Location: some text') has no meaning, header('Location: file.html') is the correct syntax.

Full code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){
  document.getElementById("form1").submit();
  document.getElementById("form2").submit();
}
</script>

<form id="form1" action="php/create.php" method="post">
Name </br><input  type="text" name="inputName" value="" id=""> </input>
Hemsida </br><input  type="text" name="inputPage" value="http://" id=""> </input>

<input type="button" onclick="return myFunction()" value="Submit" name="submit"/>

</form>
<form id="form2" action="php/createhemerb.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="inputFon" value="" id="fnid" hidden/>
<input  type="text" name="inputJob" value="" id="fnid" hidden/>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if(empty($_POST) || !$_POST['submit']) {
echo "please fill out the form";
//you can't set the header after echoing
 //header ('Location: please fill out the form 1');//use header('Location: error.html') instead.
//or output a Javascript redirect echo "<script>window.location = 'error.html';</script>";
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I get "TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function "

And sorry about the Location name, used that to know id i went though the php files at all.

Comment: Why are you even using myFunction() to submit the form? just change <input type="button> to <input type="submit"> and remove the onclick event.

Comment: When i just use submit in only submits one of the forms sadly.